# Unable to CURL POST in Python

Tags: python, url, curl, header

The API instructions that I'm following state I should do the following:

```
# Log in with a valid username and password to receive an authorization code.
curl -X POST "https://api.sensorpush.com/api/v1/oauth/authorize" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @- <<BODY
{ "email": "me@email.com", "password": "abc123" }
BODY
```

I'm not very familiar with curl requests.  After doing some research, I rewrote this in Python as:

```
import requests
from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict

url = "https://api.sensorpush.com/api/v1/oauth/authorize"
headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
headers["Content-Type"] = "applications/json"
data = "@- <<BODY { 'email': 'me@email.com', 'password': 'abc123' } BODY"

resp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)

print(resp.status_code)
```

I expected to receive an authorization code, but all it returns is "412" (with the correct email and password inserted).  This error code tells me access was denied, so I'm wondering what was incorrect about my Python code?

Comment: Can you print resp.reason instead of resp.status_code to check the reason?

Comment: To be sure, the curl command works ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this and see if it works?

```
import requests
import json
url = "https://api.sensorpush.com/api/v1/oauth/authorize"
headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json', 'accept':'application/json'}
data = { "email": "me@email.com", "password": "abc123" }
data = json.dumps(data)
r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
print(r.json())
```

Comment: you can direclty use `json=data` without using `json.dumps`.

Comment: This worked.  Looks like my headers and data needed to be formatted differently.  Thanks!